# How long will this apple compote keep in the fridge?

Tags: apples

How long will this apple compote keep in the fridge?
http://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/savory-apple-compote

Answer (score 0):

How long do you want to keep it ? 
I'd say a couple of days.
If wanting to keep it longer, I'd freeze it in portions in freezer "ziplock" bags.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a homemade compote from 48h to 7 days regarding how it is stored in the fridge, closed, the amount of sugar etc...